# How to change the URL in YII?

Tags: url, yii

Ok, let me rephrase my question.

I have a website set up with URL in "path" format, and the api function works well. 
Now I need to change only the URL of the api part in "get" format. 
For example,

```
http://localhost/api/query/data?data=100294832

http://localhost/api/data/100294832
```

works. 
api is a controller, data is a model. I have this in my main.conf,

```
array('api/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

How could I do this? Should I create an action in api called query, and moved view function code there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should works by default

Comment: Thanks Alex. I rephrased my question. Again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The URL `http://localhost/api/data/100294832` is the same as `http://localhost/api/data/?id=100294832` by your route rule. It will work by default.

Comment: But my boss wants to add "data" in front of "?", that is,http://localhost/api/data/data?id=100294832

Comment: Why is that extra `/data` required in your case? If you could let us know that, then it would be really helpful. Its more like how - `/data?data=100294832` becomes `/data/100294832` where `echo $data;` will give `100294832` in your Controller-Action.